# Clang address sanitizer detect leaks for SDL2

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sdl, sdl-2, clang++

I get leaks whenever I initialize SDL2 routines.
e.g this simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0){
        std::cerr << "SDL_Init error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

gives me using Clang flag -fsanitize=address :

```
==11672==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 12 byte(s) in 2 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x49b1db in malloc (/home/***/build/a.out+0x49b1db)
    #1 0x7f979eb12f39 in __GI___strdup (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x7ff39)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 12 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

Why do I have these memory leaks whereas gcc does not tell me anything.